# ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript

I want to load [this lightbox](https://github.com/rqrauhvmra/Tobi/) in a platform( Flarum) working on ES6 js. I'm not a developer and probably missing something as I get an error.

I have the js code in plugin-folder/js/forum/dist/extension.js as specified in their limited documentation, it gets loaded with no errors but when I try to initialize it adding `var tobi = new Tobi()` on top of the above code or with `<script></script>` in the template file containing the header I get the error `ReferenceError: Tobi is not defined`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you include the reference to the script on the page?

Comment: Try to include the script via `<script src="https://rqrauhvmra.com/tobi/tobi.js"></script>` in your page, **before** your own Javascript.

Comment: it would be much easier to answer your question if you can show us your project

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be on the side of your script import. If you load it via a `script` tag prior to any Javascript code that uses it, it works flawlessly:

```js
let tobi = new Tobi();

console.log(tobi);
```

```html
<script src="https://rqrauhvmra.com/tobi/tobi.js"></script>
```

Comment: On Flarum to make a plugin I had to make a JS/forum( and/or admin) where to put Gulp dependencies and make another two folders: src where to put my JS file, and a dist folder where to have the same JS file converted in ES6 format used by Flarum. Since tobi lightbox code was already ES6 just copy pasted it in the JS file inside dist folder. And the file looks [like that](https://github.com/ckubs/test/blob/master/extension.js)